# Different timestamps under winXP, win7 and vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net, timezone, dst

Within a VB.net program I used IO.File.GetCreationTime to read the file system's creation time of a file. I was irritated, because the returned value didn't match with the time displayed in the explorer. On another machine the time was displayed correctly.

- Both machines use NTFS
- I copied the file from a read-only FAT32 USB-drive to the desktop of each machine
- Both machines are using the same time zone (GMT+1 plus DST)

timestamps displayed:

- my VB.net app (both machines) - 21:09
- Explorer time Windows XP - 22:09
- Explorer time Windows 7 - 21:09
- (MacOS X - 21:09)

The good thing is, that the file I'm talking about is a PDF file. According to the PDF's meta information the file was created on **03. Jan. 2002 22:09**

I want that the file system dates are the same on every machine.
How would you solve this problem using VB.net?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but could it be that the modified time is for some reason returned as UTC time instead of local time? Try calling `dateVar.ToLocalTime()` (or whatever the VB.NET equivalent is) to ensure it is local time and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I would be similarly curious what happens when you output [`dateTime.ToFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime.aspx) and [`dateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx). The documentation for [`System.IO.File.GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime.aspx) claims that the `DateTime` returned is in local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a simple app to summarize the timestamp information:

```
GetLastWriteTime(file)
GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file)
GetLastWriteTime(file).ToLocalTime
GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file).ToLocalTime
GetLastWriteTime(file).ToFileTime
GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file).ToFileTime

Date.Now
Date.Now.UtcNow
```

The output was the same on both machines.
For some reason I changed the time zone settings on both machines, switching DST on and off. The result is interesting ...

- ... when you turn off DST on Windows
  XP **all** time stamps are reduced by
  one (because during DST my time zone
  is **GMT+2 (now)**, during the
  wintertime it is GMT+1)
- ... on a Windows 7 machine **only
  files created during DST (GMT+2)**
  are affected by this (my file was
  created in January)

I guess it's the same effect vice versa. So my problem is just a disply issue. To solve this I will only use the UTC-Functions and care about DST within my app. So there still will be an offset, but it should be ok as long as it is just a display issue.